# problems getting ActiveMerchant PayPal Gateway to work on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, activemerchant

I am trying to get PayPal Gateway to work on a rails 3 app.
But I keep hitting this error "uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Billing::PayPalGateway (NameError)"

I've this in my development.rb:

`ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test

   ::GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PayPalGateway.new(

        :login =>  "API USERNAME ",

        :password => "API PASSWORD",

        :signature => "API SIGNATURE" 

)`

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your capitalisation is wrong. Try:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway
```